# Itext pdf, how to draw string to specific location?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to use Itext to output some strings to a PDF. Currently I can print them to the document but I would like to draw/write them to a specific (x,y) in the document. How would I go about this? Or is there any tutorial or resource that can help? Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but if you're using iText 7 you can use the [`Canvas` class](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-2-adding-low-level-content) (towards the bottom of that page) and if you're using iText 5 you can use a [`ColumnText`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples/positioning-different-text-snippets-page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using iText 5, please go to the FAQ section conveniently titled as [Absolute positioning of text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text)

You'll find answers to questions such as [How to write a Zapfdingbats character at a specific location on a page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-write-zapfdingbats-character-specific-location-page) In the answer to that question, we use `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(zapfstring, font);
```

Where `zapfstring` is a string containing any Zapfdingbats character you want and `font` is a `Font` object. Then we add it at an absolute position:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, x, y, 0);
```

If you want to add text inside a rectangle (text wraps if it doesn't fit the width), take a look at this question: [How to add text inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-inside-rectangle)

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
ct.setSimpleColumn(rect);
ct.addElement(new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle"));
ct.go();
```

If you are using iText 7, use the `setFixedPosition()` method, for instance on the `Paragraph` object.