# Wrap text written within user defined area in pdf

Tags: itext

We have a requirement where user wants to write some content from the db to selected areas in pdf.  We provide this option by asking the user to upload pdf to the system, after drawing rectangular markups within. Later he can define rules as to what content he can write to the defined area. We use iText for all operations like reading coordinates of the drawn markups, writing content to the defined area.

Now the challenge is that we need to wrap the text within the area that the user has defined. We use the ColumnText class to write the content. Is there anyway we can wrap the text within the area? Posting this query from mobile. So couldn't upload any helpful code.

Comment: Are you using a `Paragraph` within your `ColumnText`? It should wrap automatically.

Comment: Ok. I will try that and update.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this (very recent) question: [Itext pdf, how to draw string to specific location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226923/itext-pdf-how-to-draw-string-to-specific-location) The second code sample is what you need `ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas); ct.setSimpleColumn(rect); ct.addElement(new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle")); ct.go();` More examples can be found in the FAQ section [Absolute positioning of text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text)